# apache cxf: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied

Tags: spring-boot, soap, cxf

Java 17, CXF in version 4.0.0 [cxf-rt-ws-security, cxf-rt-transports-http, cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws]

I try to create my client like this:
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setWsdlLocation(wssProperties.getServiceUrl());
factoryBean.setProperties(jaxwsProperties());

```
    factoryBean.setAddress("https://link");
    String nameSpace = "http://namespace";
    factoryBean.setEndpointName(new QName(nameSpace, "RegisterSth"));
    factoryBean.setServiceName(new QName(nameSpace, "registerSth"));
    factoryBean.setInInterceptors(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new LoggingInInterceptor())));
    factoryBean.setOutInterceptors(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new LoggingOutInterceptor())));

    RegisterPrepaid registerPrepaid = factoryBean.create(RegisterPrepaid.class);
```

This is my properties method:

```
private Map<String, Object> jaxwsProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("ws-security.callback-handler", keystorePasswordCallback());
    properties.put("ws-security.encryption.properties", keystoreProperties());
    properties.put("ws-security.signature.properties", keystoreProperties());
    properties.put("ws-security.encryption.username", wssProperties.getServerKeyAlias());
    properties.put("ws-security.asymmetric.signature.algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1");

    return properties;
}
```

and:

```
@Bean
public Properties keystoreProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_TYPE, wssProperties.getKeystoreType());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, wssProperties.getKeystorePassword());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_ALIAS, wssProperties.getKeyAlias());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_FILE, wssProperties.getKeystoreFileSystemPath());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.TRUSTSTORE_FILE, wssProperties.getKeystoreFileSystemPath());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, wssProperties.getKeystorePassword());
    properties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.TRUSTSTORE_TYPE, wssProperties.getKeystoreType());

    return properties;
}
```

My WSDL contains X509Token in AsymmetricBinding and algorithm with Basic256 policy.
When I use it, I still get this error "None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied."
And before it: "Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath:"

Anyone can help? I have correct namespaces (I think) and no other ideas what is wrong.

Comment: @Colm O hEigeartaigh maybe you can give me some hint?

Comment: could it be conflict with dependencies. seems like WSS4J is not updated in CXF https://github.com/apache/cxf/pull/1476/commits/d00f7459f63288e4683d4c961cc2d09fb07e9384